# I cannot get /users json

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to express and node js, I recently learned how to write API for express but at the end, I get some sort of problem which not resolved by me after several tries. I could not get a response on localhost:8080/users

src/routes/users.js

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const router = Router();

const getUsers = (req, res) =>
  res.send(Object.values(req.context.models.users));
const getUser = (req, res) =>
  res.send(req.context.models.users[req.params.userId]);

router.get("/users/", getUsers);
router.get("/users/:userId", getUser);

module.exports = router;
```

src/routes/index.js

```
const user = require("./user");
const message = require("./message");

module.exports = {
  user,
  message
};
```

src/index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// Custom Modules
const routes = require("./routes");
const models = require("./models");

// Application-Level Middleware Starts
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.context = {
    models,
    me: models.users[1]
  };
  console.log(req.context.models.users);
  next();
});

// Used Routes

app.use("/users", routes.user);
app.use("/messages", routes.message);

// App Listning to HTTPS Module
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Comment: Is there any error shows in the terminal while running index.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your endpoints in *users.js*:

```
router.get("/", getUsers);
router.get("/:userId", getUser);
```

The reason is because of `app.use("/users", routes.user);` in your *index.js*, where the endpoint for users is set. If you leave `/users/` in *users.js* it would be *localhost:8080/users/users/*. Same problem might be with */messages*.